# Apostrophe in php query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains name of movies and other things and in my php page I want to select some of that movies..

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Movies where Movies.nameM='{$row['nameM']}';";
```

This query crashes when the `nameM` (name of movie) has an apostrophe in its name :/

How can I change this to work well?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're having this problem, you should have a very, very good look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I downvoted because I feel it lacks research effort. Nothing personal.

Comment: Which MySQL functions are you using?  If you use prepared statements, this issue would be a thing of the past :)

Comment: (1) Google for "SQL injection". Read and discover why you need to be really *really* careful when building DB strings. (2) Start using the PDO library for your PHP DB code, and use its "Prepared Statement" functionality to get around this issue. (3) Find a few *good quality* PHP tutorials (eg http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases).

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Movies where Movies.nameM='".mysqli_real_escape_string($row['nameM'])."';";
```

And if you are using the old and deprecated `mysql_*` functions:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Movies where Movies.nameM='".mysql_real_escape_string($row['nameM'])."';";
```

Comment: this is by far the most appropriate answer. might you also add an example using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for backward compatibility purposes?

Comment: MySQL_* functions are now deprecated, so shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

As Spudley said you should R&D more. Just to make it a few easier for you

You may use mysql(i)_ real escape functions but if you're using a framework works on top of PDO you don't have a mysql(i)_* connection and can't escape strings using them
i have seen this problem previously on yii or f3 or ...
Mostly the frameworks support the param safe injection.

```
\Framework::Query("SELECT .... WHERE column=:param", array(':param'=>$value));
```

But some times you may need to escape the string value manually. To do that with PDO you can acquire the pdo object and use the :

```
substr($pdo->quote($string, , \PDO::PARAM_STR), 1, -1)
```

The only note is that the ->quote() also puts the apostrophes around the result which they can get wiped using substr.

**Edited to make the codes clear**